# Cookbook name prefix when calling LWRP

Tags: chef-infra

## Summary

Can I use an LWRP from an external cookbook without prefixing the cookbooks name? For example, if `mycookbook` contains the `mylwrp` resource how can I do this?

```
include_recipe 'mycookbook' # Contains "mylwrp"
mylwrp "frobulator" do
   frobulations 42
end
```

## Details

I have written an LWRP that gets the name `mycookbook_mylwrp` since the library cookbook uses the normal resources/provider layout as follows

```
mycookbook/
├── providers
│   └── mylwrp.rb
└── resources
    └── mylwrp.rb
```

Would it be possible to

- Keep the LWRP in the `mycookbook` cookbook
- Use the LWRP without prefixing the `mycookbook` name (`mycookbook_mylwrp`)

I realise that I can create a whole new cookbook and call it "mylwrp" and use the default providers as follows

```
mylwrp/
├── providers
│   └── default.rb
└── resources
    └── default.rb
```

but then I have to make dedicated cookbooks for each LWRP I want to use in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use HWRPs.  These go in the `libraries` directory rather than `resources` and `providers`.  If you go that route, I'd look into the `poise` library which allows you to write HWRPs with the same finesse as LWRPs.

Now, all that said, you are doing something that is decidedly outside the norm.  The community is used to custom providers being namespaced to match the cookbook that declares them.  If you want to share this cookbook with the community, you're going to cause some confusion.  Even if you only use it internally, it will steepen the learning curve for any new members you bring onto your team.  So unless you have a compelling reason to do it, I'd strongly suggest you avoid it.

On the other hand, if you do have a compeling reason, I'd suggest you share it so we can all benefit from your thoughts.

Comment: The reason was mostly cosmetic so leaning towards just putting the LWRP in it's own cookbook to get the desired named. But this is good info, thanks.

Comment: @FredClausen if they're tightly related resources, I'd really suggest you look at `poise`.  It makes writing HWRPs as easy as writing LWRPs.  I'm going to go on a limb and coin a new term and call them MWRP (middle-weight resource providers).

Comment: They're not tightly related so my feeling is having them in separate cookbooks is better. That said I'm definitely going to read about ```poise``` in case I need to do this in the future. And see what else poise offers.

Answer (score 0):

No, LWRPs are all global and so are namespaced by the cookbook to prevent collisions. You also don't need the include_recipe, that is only involved in running recipe code. You do need the `depends` line in the metadata.rb though.

Comment: On the Chef IRC they mentioned that using a HWRP might be a way to go.

Comment: That is a bit more complex but does allow direct control over class naming. You haven't really given much backstory as to why you think this is a good idea. If you are trying to do some kind of fancy dependency injection thing, there are other options, and I will point out again that resources and providers are global so you can't reuse existing names.